# Example of a filter $G$ on $\mathbb{P}$ for which $\mathbb{P}\setminus G\notin M[G]$.

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

This is exercise IV.2.47 from Kunen's Set Theory.

> Assume that M is a ctm for ZFC Give an example of a $\mathbb{P}\in M$ and a (non-generic) filter G on P for which $(\mathbb{P}\setminus G)\notin M[G].$

It includes this hint:

> Hint: One could let $\mathbb{P}$ be HF ,and let $\leq$ be an appropriate forcing order such that $p\leq q \leq p$ whenever rank($p$)=rank($q$). Then $G$ can be built by a diagonal argument. Observe that for filters, $G \subseteq H \implies rank(\tau_G)\leq rank(\tau_H)$.

I am very confused about what Kunen is suggesting I diagonalize or how I'm supposed to take advantage of the last observation. I studied the fact that $\mathring{G} = \{(\check{p},q):p,q\in\mathbb{P}\land p\perp q\}$ names $\mathbb{P}\setminus G$ whenever $G$ is generic and how this name can sometimes fail (for example when $G=\{\mathbb{1}\}$) but it hasn't helped.

I've also been trying to construct $G$ by induction on some well order of HF in such a way that I never add a name that names $\mathbb{P}\setminus G$, but haven't been succesful.

Can anybody guide me in some way towards the solution? Thank you.

Comment: Not having read through Kunen's presentation of forcing, I have a question. Let $M$ be some $L_\xi$ which satisfies ZFC. Does Kunen's $M[G]$ differ from the $L_\xi[G]$ given by the usual notion of relative constructibility? It would seem that one can show by induction on $\eta$ that $\{L_\beta\mid\beta\lt\eta\}\in L_{\eta+\omega}[G]$ for all $\eta\lt\xi;$ so $L_\xi\subseteq L_\xi[G]$ (even though $L_\xi[G]$ may not satisfy ZFC). But then $\mathbb{P}$ is in some $L_\eta[G]$ for $\eta\lt\xi,$ so $G\in L_{\eta+1}[G],$ and $\mathbb{P}\setminus G\in L_{\eta+2}[G]\subseteq L_\xi[G].$

Comment: @Stefan Certainly $L_\xi[G]$ may not be a model of ZFC, but what is eluding me is: how can $\mathbb{P}\setminus G$ fail to be in $L_\xi[G]?$ (This is the claim in the exercise quoted from Kunen, assuming that $M[G]$ is the same as the usual $L_\xi[G].)$ We would seem to have that $\mathbb{P}$ is in some $L_\eta[G]$ by the argument in my previous comment, so $\mathbb{P}\setminus G=\{x\mid x\in\mathbb{P}\land x \not\in G\}$ is first-order definable over $\langle L_\eta[G];\in, G\rangle,$ and it follows that $\mathbb{P}\setminus G\in L_{\eta+1}[G] \subseteq L_{\xi}[G].$

Comment: @Mitchell Well, $M[G]$ and $L_\xi[G]$ can differ. We can for example arrange that $G \not \in L_\xi[G]$. And this is the point where your argument in your first comment fails. If $G \in L_{\eta + 1}[G]$ for some $\eta < \xi$, then surely $\mathbb P \setminus G \in L_\xi[G]$. But this need not to be the case. I thought that I had a proof of this exercise, but that didn't work out... I'll think about it a little longer.

Comment: @Stefan I haven't read Kunen's approach, but I would have expected $L_{\eta+1}[G]$ to contain every set first-order definable over $\langle L_\eta[G];\in;G\rangle,$ where $G$ is the relation $G(x)\iff x\in G\cap L_\eta[G].$ If that's right, and if $\mathscr{P}\in L_\eta[G],$ then $G$ must be in $L_{\eta+1}[G].$ Maybe there's something wrong with the argument that $\mathscr{P}$ must be in some $L_\eta[G]$ for some $\eta\lt\xi?$  It's surely true that $\mathscr{P}$ is in $L_\eta$ for some $\eta\lt\xi.$

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I think this does the job.

First of all, let's recall the definition of $M[G]$ which Kunen uses (and which, to address Mitchell's comments, *is* different from the $L$-style definition): $$M[G]=\{\nu[G]: \nu\in M^\mathbb{P}\},$$ that is, $M[G]$ is the set of all $\mathbb{P}$-names in $M$ evaluated at $G$. Note that the evaluation of a name $\nu$ at $G$ makes sense for $G$ an *arbitrary subset* of $\mathbb{P}$ (not even a filter!): it's defined inductively as $\{(p_i, \nu_i): i\in I\}[G]=\{\nu_i[G]: p_i\in G\}$. Of course, this is much less natural if $G$ isn't a filter.

The key point is that $\nu[G]$ is a **positive object**: we determine positive facts about membership in $\nu[G]$ based on positive facts about membership in $G$. Now, if $G$ is a *generic* filter, then each negative fact is determined by a positive fact: if $p\not\in G$, then there's some $q\in G$ which prevented $p$ from being in $G$. However, if $G$ isn't generic, this breaks down, and now - if we want to show that $\mathbb{P}\setminus G\in M[G]$ - we're faced with the task of giving a *positive* description of a *negatively-defined* object.

And the point is that there's no reason in general to believe this can be done.

*A tangent: there are often interesting analogies to be drawn between forcing and ideas from computability theory; here, the one that leaps out to me is the distinction between [Turing reducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) and [enumeration reducibility](https://store.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/fmi/logic/asoskova/Istanbul2min.pdf), in the context of pinning down this positive/negative distinction.*

---

Alright, so that's the intuition; how are we going to build the desired $\mathbb{P}$ and $G$? I'm going to depart from Kunen's hint here, since frankly I don't find it very helpful. I'm also going to try to do something a bit more interesting than just solving the problem as stated:

> Claim: there is some $\mathbb{P}\in M$, some $\mathbb{Q}\in M$, some $H$ which is $\mathbb{Q}$-generic over $M$, and some name $\mu\in M^\mathbb{Q}$ such that $G=\mu[H]$ is a (non-generic) filter through $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{P}\setminus G\not\in M[G]$.

That is, *a desired counterexample can be built by actual forcing*! This is actually already implicit in Kunen's hint: "by diagonalization" is slang for "using forcing" :P.

Alright, how are we going to do it? Well, we want our $\mathbb{P}$ to have lots of compatibilities, so that "positive" information doesn't give us "negative" information (e.g. the poset $2^{<\omega}$ would be a *bad* idea, since e.g. knowing $01001\in G$ would tell us $01000\not\in G$). Let's take something really simple - say, $\mathbb{P}=\mathcal{P}_{fin}(\omega)$, ordered by inclusion. From the perspective of forcing, this is a very silly poset since it has no incompatibilities at all! But it still has lots of *incomparabilities*, and so many (non-generic) filters.

Now we want our $\mathbb{Q}$ to build a "bad" filter through $\mathbb{P}$. How will we do this? Well, we have a bunch of requirements to meet: for each $\nu\in M^\mathbb{P}$, we need to satisfy $$\nu[G]\not=\mathbb{P}\setminus G$$ (where $G=\mu[H]$ - we haven't specified what $\mu$ is, or even what $\mathbb{Q}$ is, so this is all vague; the only point is to build a bit of intuition). To satisfy this, we want our $G$ to have lots of negative information which can't be detected; put another way, $H$ needs to build $G$ by making both positive *and negative* declarations about $G$ (so that $G$ has lots of negative information folded into it). So one natural guess for $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of *pairs* $(A, B)$ of disjoint finite sets of natural numbers, ordered by $$(A, B)\le(C, D)\iff A\supseteq C, B\supseteq D.$$ (Note that this is just Cohen forcing in disguise.) The generic $H$ is essentially a partition of $\omega$, and we'll let $G$ be the left side of the partition; formally, we let $$G=\{n: \exists (A, B)\in H(n\in A)\}.$$ If you prefer to be super-formal, the specific name $\mu$ we're looking at is $$\mu=\{((A, B), \check{n}): n\in A\}.$$

I claim this does the job. So let $H$ be $\mathbb{Q}$-generic over $M$, and $G=\mu[H]$; I claim that $\mathbb{P}\setminus G\not\in M[G]$. To show this, it will be enough to argue that for each $\nu\in M^\mathbb{P}$, we have $\nu[G]\not=\mathbb{P}\setminus G$. We'll argue via genericity, as usual. So fix a $\nu\in M^\mathbb{P}$ and a condition $q\in\mathbb{Q}$; we'll find a $q'\le q$ which forces $\nu[G]\not=\mathbb{P}\setminus[G]$.

There are a few ways to do this; I like the following. Let $q=(A, B)$, fix some $n\not\in A\cup B$, and let $q_0=(A, B\cup\{n\})$. Then WLOG we can find some $q_1=(A', B')\le q_0$ such that $A'\vdash n\in \nu$; otherwise, take $q'=q_0$ (since $\nu[G]$ will now be guaranteed to *not* see that $n\in\mathbb{P}\setminus G$).

OK, now let $q'=(A'\cup\{n\}, B)$, and think about what $q'$ forces about what $\nu$ thinks about $\mathbb{P}\setminus G$ . . . $\Box$